# IllegalAccessException ao ler valores com reflection

Tags: java, android, reflexão

Não consigo ler os valores dos atributos da classe com reflection:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field: fields ) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        values.put(field.getName(), field.get(this.getClass()));
    }
```

Tenho a exceção: `IllegalAccessException`  no método get: `field.get(this.getClass())`
Também tentei `field.get(this)` e ainda passando a instância do objeto `field.get(model)`

Os atributos do objeto model não são privados. Se não usar o metodo `field.setAccessible(true);` a exceção é a mesma.

A pedido do amigo Ramaral, segue a classe toda:

```
public class GenericModel {

    public Long id;

    public ContentValues GetContentValues()
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field: fields ) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                values.put(field.getName(), field.get(this.getClass()));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            }
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código nem sequer compila.

Comment: Não manjo muito de reflection, mas acho que precisa previnir exception com try nos métodos dinâmicos, assim compila, mas não executa de acordo. Se tiver sugestão com outros métodos ou pattern

Comment: Sim tem de colocar o try/catch mas a linha `values.put(field.getName(), field.get(this.getClass()));` continuará a dar erro. Só por si `field.get(this.getClass())` não deveria dar erro. Edite a pergunta e coloque os atributos da classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem 3 coisas erradas no seu código:

1. O método *Field#get()* retorna um objecto, é necessário fazer o cast para um tipo que o *ContentValues#put()* aceite e esse tipo deve ser compatível com o tipo do campo em causa.

   ```
   (Long)field.get(...)
   ```
2. Ao método *Field#get()* deve ser passado o objecto que contem o campo representado por este Field e cujo valor se quer obter.

   ```
   (Long)field.get(this)
   ```
3. O campo `id` tem de ser inicializado.

   ```
   public Long id = 3l;
   ```

Com as alterações ficará assim:

```
public class GenericModel {

    public Long id = 3l;

    public ContentValues GetContentValues()
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field: fields ) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            try {
                values.put(field.getName(), (Long)field.get(this));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                //Faça algo aqui, nem que seja apenas um log
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

**Nota:**
Se *GenericModel* tiver mais campos e estes não sejam todos do tipo `Long` terá de alterar o método `GetContentValues()` para lidar com essa situação.

Comment: Obrigado pelo empenho e auxilio. Parece funcionar.
Tive que fazer o switch no Type do Field.